# Excel Formula with OFFSET Fails When Copied to Different Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been struggling with this longer than I care to admit, but I have a fairly simple `OFFSET` function call which works on one sheet, but if I copy it to a different sheet it gives a `#VALUE` error.

On a sheet named "Deliverable" I have this formula in a cell:

```
=OFFSET(Deliverable!$B$72,1,0,,3)
```

and it works fine.

If I go to any other sheet and use the same exact formula, or use it in the Name Manager, it gives a `#VALUE` error.

If I leave off the final parameter indicated the number of columns I want, it does work:

```
=OFFSET(Deliverable!$B$72,1,0)
```

but of course isn't giving me the range I need.

Any idea what's going on with this?

I'm using Excel 2016 on Windows 7.

-- Updated Info --
In a nutshell, my spreadsheet has two cells which I'm using as dropdown lists, where the 2nd cell's list feeds off the selection in the first.  The data they are based on has this format:

```
OptionA     A     B     C     D
OptionB     A     B
OptionC     D     E     F
```

So the first dropdown uses a simple Data Validation source pointing to the column with OptionA, OptionB, etc.  Once that's chosen, the second dropdown list should contain the appropriate options for the one selected.  So if OptionB is selected, then the 2nd dropdown list should show A and B.

When I initially wrote this, the data validation source was just a simple VLOOKUP entry, but the lists often had blanks since the number of options varies for each entry.  Wanting to fix it up a bit, I ended up with this formula:
    `=OFFSET(Deliverable!B72,Deliverable!B87,0,1,COUNTA(OFFSET(Deliverable!B72,Deliverable!B87,0,1,5)))`

There won't be any more than 5 options, and there are no empty cells in the middle of the data to filter out.

In one spreadsheet I have I used this as a named range definition, then specified the named range for the cells data validation source and it worked.  In this other spreadsheet however, it gave me the error described earlier.

However, it looks like when I enter the statement directly into the data validation source field and not in the name manager, it works as expected.

Am I taking the totally wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

What is it that you want this formula to do? As written, it is returning a block of three horizontal cells. The #VALUE error is Excel's way of telling you "Hey, you're trying to return three cells, but I can't fit them all in the one cell that you are calling this formula from".

The reason you see a result in some places and not others is because of something called Implicit Intersection. Give it a spin on Google. But basically, it just returns whichever one of those three results corresponds to the column that the formula is entered into. If you copy that exact same formula to say row F you will see that it returns a #VALUE error there, because it doesn't know what cell it should return given the column you're calling it from doesn't match any of the cells it is returning. The fact that you don't know this indicates that the formula you're using doesn't in fact do what you think it does.

--UPDATE --

Okay, following your further clarificaiton it seems that you're talking about Cascading Dropdowns aka Dynamic Dropdowns. Lots of info on Google about how to set these up, but you may be interested in an approach I blogged about sometime back that not only provides this functionality, but also ensures that someone can't later on go and change the 'upstream' dropdown without first clearing the 'downstream' one should they want to make a change.

Note that those links talk about a slightly complicated method compared to others, but the method has it's advantages in that it also handles more levels than two, and your DV lists are easily maintained as they live in an Excel Table.

Comment: Thanks @jeffrey.  I'll look more closely at Implicit Intersection.  I've also edited the original post with more details on what exactly I was trying to do.  Your last comment basically saying I don't know what I'm doing could be accurate.

Comment: Cool...I was hoping you wouldn't take that the wrong way :-)

Comment: Ahhh...you're talking about cascading dropdowns. I'll edit my post with a few links. Yes, there are easier ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like an array equation. Try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the other sheets to validate it as an array equation.

Whenever you need to reference ranges instead of single cells, Excel needs to know that you are working with arrays.

Comment: Thanks Alexis.  That helps me part of the way since it now works on other sheets, although I'm still not sure why it works when the formula is on the same sheet as the data?  Is there a trick to get it working correctly in the name manager?  My goal is to use the data returned by the function in a dropdown list.

Comment: @Bill Is it already an array formula on the `Deliverable` sheet? (Check if it's wrapped in braces `{...}`.) When I try adding an offset formula to the name manager, it seems to treat it as a range just fine.

Comment: no braces or brackets.  I now have it working by typing in the formula directly into the data validation source instead of creating a named range.  It's still a mystery as to why it works fine in one spreadsheet but not this other one, and why I can't copy it between different sheets (which I was doing to test that it was working, not to actually use it in a cell).  Original post was modified with more details.